# How to implement and invoke utility methods in Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to implement reusable functions/methods to use in my Jenkins pipeline...

```
 listAllUnitTests([
      $class: 'MyUtilities',
      arg1: 'foo',
      arg2: 'bar'
      ])
```

What's not clear is how to actually do it; is this a plugin, extension, what is it?

### The Hunt

So I started with something familiar, such as Git `checkout`...

```
node {
    checkout([
         $class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: scm.branches,
         extensions: scm.extensions,
         userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
    ])
 }
```

Looking at the source for [GitSCM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java), a Jenkins plugin, the `checkout` method appears to be fairly standard; no special annotations or anything else, although I'm not sure how the pipeline arguments align with the method signature because there's clearly a mismatch. I suspect I'm on the wrong track.

```
@Override
public void checkout(
   Run<?, ?> build,
   Launcher launcher,
   FilePath workspace,
   TaskListener listener,
   File changelogFile,
   SCMRevisionState baseline)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

## Question

I'll keep it simple: how do I implement parameterized functionality to invoke from Jenkins pipelines to achieve something like this?

```
node {
  stage('test'){

     myUtilMethod([
          $class: 'MyUtilities',
          arg1: 'foo',
          arg2: 'bar'
          ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement one or more libraries using https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/

I recommend explicitly specifying that you need the library (with the `@Library` annotation as mentioned in the page above), and not make it implicitly available. This way you can use a specific branch of it on test jobs while developing and testing your library.

Check out fabric8 for a pretty comprehensive set of examples: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library

Comment: So, technically, `GitSCM.checkout()` is a Jenkins library function call?

Comment: "checkout" is a step, which is slightly different, even if you use it the same way. For example, in the build log, you see entries for each step, but for your library code you only see entries for the steps they use. You can view the stuff in vars/ as fields that get automatically added to your script, and since they have a class with the call() method, the fields become callable.